# Cannot connect to RDS Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I have setup a Postgres RDS Instance in EU Ireland. I have kept all outbound traffic as 0.0.0.0/0 and inbound traffic as :-

```
Type        Protocol        Port Range   Source   Description
PostgreSQL    TCP              5432     0.0.0.0/0
```

When I try to connect to RDS from my mac terminal I get this error -

```
psql --host=test.XXXXX.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com --port=5432 --username=testuser --password --dbname=testdb
Password: 
psql: could not connect to server: Operation timed out
    Is the server running on host "test.XXXXX.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (34.255.150.234) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I am based in Frankfurt but I am deploying the server in Ireland because I want to use AWS QuickSight which is not available in Frankfurt for now.

My OS Firewall is off as well. Public access is set to YES.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, you didn't allow public access when you were creating your RDS instance. Change RDS instance properties to enable public access.

[image]

Comment: Then it's likely that you've created your RDS instance in a VPC that doesn't have outside connectivity. Check the route table and internet gateway for this VPC.